# summarytools error while knitting in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, tapply, summarytools

I am knitting a code below in R Markdown (I work on ESS9 data: https://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/data/download.html?r=9)

```
ess$social_trust<-rowSums(select(ess, ppltrst, pplfair, pplhlp), na.rm=TRUE)
tapply(ess$social_trust, ess$gndr, dfSummary) 
tapply(ess$social_trust, ess$gndr, freq)`
```

The code works while being run manually (also in a separate R document) but after knitting (both to pdf and HTML) I receive such errors:

`tapply(ess$social_trust, ess$gndr, dfSummary)`

```
## X[[i]] was converted to a data frame
## X[[i]] was converted to a data frame

## x must either be a summarytools object created with freq(), descr(), or a list of summarytools objects created using by()
```

`tapply(ess$social_trust, ess$gndr, freq)`

```
## x must either be a summarytools object created with freq(), descr(), or a list of summarytools objects created using by()
```

The solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862226/is-there-a-way-to-display-multiple-tables-in-the-rstudio-viewer) doesn't work.

I will be grateful for your support!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to loop over the objects inside the object created by tapply:

```
tlist <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, list(iris$Species), dfSummary)
for (obj in tlist)
  print(obj)
```

(A fix will be included in version 1.0.1)